# How to sample random numbers of particular variance from truncated normal distribution?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to sample numbers from truncated normal distribution given particular variance and bounds of the resulting numbers, e.g. I need numbers with mean 0 and unit variance, but they must be within some bounds, for example [-2, 2]

I can't figure out how to truncate the distribution while keeping the variance.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats


truncation = 2
lower, upper = -truncation, truncation
mu, sigma = 0, 1
num_samples = 1000
if truncation:
    n = stats.truncnorm((lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    samples = n.rvs(num_samples)
    std_trunc = np.std(samples)

    n = stats.norm(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    samples = n.rvs(num_samples)
    std_simple = np.std(samples)

print(std_trunc, std_simple, sep='\n')

# outputs 
# 0.859167285015  # I need number close to 1 here
# 1.01735583631  # like here, but here it's not truncated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia page gives expressions for the [observed mean and variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#Moments), and we can use that to invert to find out what values we should pass to `truncnorm` to give us the outcome we want.

We won't take advantage of any simplifications based on working with the standard normal, partly to be general and partly because I haven't had breakfast yet so I don't want to do any arithmetic.. probably you can replace the entire minimization with a simple calculation.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.optimize

def truncated_mean_std(mu, sigma, lower, upper):
    # N.B. lower/upper are the actual values, not Z-scaled
    alpha = (lower - mu)/sigma
    beta = (upper - mu)/sigma
    d_pdf = (stats.norm.pdf(alpha) - stats.norm.pdf(beta))
    wd_pdf = (alpha * stats.norm.pdf(alpha) - beta * stats.norm.pdf(beta))
    d_cdf = stats.norm.cdf(beta) - stats.norm.cdf(alpha)
    mu_trunc = mu + sigma * (d_pdf / d_cdf)
    var_trunc = sigma**2 * (1 + wd_pdf / d_cdf - (d_pdf/d_cdf)**2)
    std_trunc = var_trunc**0.5
    return mu_trunc, std_trunc

def trunc_samples(mu, sigma, lower, upper, num_samples=1000):
    n = stats.truncnorm((lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    samples = n.rvs(num_samples)
    return samples

def corrector(mu, sigma, lower, upper):
    target = np.array([mu, sigma])
    result = scipy.optimize.minimize(
        lambda x: ((target - truncated_mean_std(x[0], x[1], lower, upper))**2).sum(),
        x0=[mu, sigma])
    return result.x
```

which gives me:

```
In [79]: s = trunc_samples(mu=0, sigma=1, lower=-2, upper=2, num_samples=10**7)

In [80]: s.mean(), s.std()
Out[80]: (-9.8821067931585576e-05, 0.87951241887015619)

In [81]: mu_to_use, sigma_to_use = corrector(0, 1, -2, 2)

In [82]: mu_to_use, sigma_to_use
Out[82]: (-7.4553057719882245e-09, 1.3778928137492246)

In [83]: s = trunc_samples(mu=mu_to_use, sigma=sigma_to_use, lower=-2, upper=2, num_samples=10**7)

In [84]: s.mean(), s.std()
Out[84]: (0.0004091647648333381, 0.99991490259048865)

In [85]: s.min(), s.max()
Out[85]: (-1.9999995310631815, 1.9999997070340947)
```

Comment: works great, but for some values the corrector gives negative std. e.g. for the following inputs: 0, 0.08838834764831845, -0.1767766952966369, 0.1767766952966369

Comment: @Bob it seems to me that `truncated_mean_std` returns mean-like and std-like values, i.e. values compatible with `mu` and `sigma`, respectively. This implies that in the call to `minimize` in `corrector` you actually want to minimize against `[mu, sigma]` rather than `[mu, sigma**2]`. If you remove the square from the definition of `target` in the first line of `corrector`, you start getting reasonable std values.

Comment: Oops, fixed.  You can even see in the code that I switched from variance to stddev at the last second -- I didn't spot the mistake because 1^2 = 1. :-)  Also don't forget that you don't have as much freedom as you might want -- the truncated stddev will always be smaller than the original, and since the variance is just a measure of how far things are away from the mean on average, when you truncate you put a limit on that.  There's a variance beyond which you can't go -- you can watch the limit be approached just by passing a larger and larger sigma to truncnorm.